# Code reusability on C# for analogue gauge AGauge

Tags: c#, visual-studio, methods, simulator

I need help to reuse a code written in C#.

I am preparing an assignment for school where we need to write a program in C# to visually show values of some sensors. I have used random number generator and AGauge to do this.
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/448562/An-Improved-Version-of-AGauge-A-fast-and-performin
Is there a way, I can reuse the code for more than 1 Gauges, instead of editing and copying the code one by one.
I am quite new to C# and programming in general. I have been studying the internet for preparing the necessary code.

```
  //Reactor Instrument  start
    int inst1 = 0; //for counting alarms

    Random rnd = new Random();
    int randlow = 400; //simulation low
    int randhigh = 410;//simulation high

    if (btnTestWasClicked != false) //alarm test
    {
        gReactor.Value = gReactor.MaxValue; //setting high value
        btnTestWasClicked = false;
    }
    else
    {
        gReactor.Value = Convert.ToInt16(rnd.Next(randlow,randhigh));
    }
    lblReactor.Text = Convert.ToString(gReactor.Value) + "°C";

    var forpriority = gReactor.Value;

    if (forpriority >= 420 || forpriority <= 300) //activating alarms
    {
        inst1 = 1;
        pictureBox1.Visible = true;
        lblReactor.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        button1WasClicked = false;

    }

    else if (button1WasClicked != false)
    {
        pictureBox1.Visible = false;
        lblReactor.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
    }
    //reactr Instrument end
```

If this is not possible, I will copy paste and change variable names.
Thanks for the help so far!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wrap in a function call, and use greactor, lblreactor and pictureox 2 as patamerter to that function and then call it with the different ui elements